# How to sort a model using .order instead of .sort_by?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Product has many product attributes:

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_attributes
end

class ProductAttribute < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end
```

I can sort it with `sort_by`:

```rb
@products.includes(:product_attributes).to_a.sort_by do |product|
  product.product_attributes.find_by(title: "Volume").value.to_i
end
```

Is it possible to make the same sort with `order` method?
I don’t understand how to order by particular attribute title (like "Volume", etc).

```rb
@products = Product.includes(:product_attributes).order( ??? )
```

Here is similar question:
[Rails - Sort by join table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197649/rails-sort-by-join-table-data)
Maybe I don't see the obvious, but I think it doesn't answer my question. I select item not by attribute name, but by attribute value, like "Volume".
In other words, I `find_by` by attribute's value with title "Volume" (look at the code above).
And I don't understand how to make such selection with `order`.

Comment: You can do this with a scope, as in the linked answer, or by just appending the scope components to `Product`.

Comment: You'll need a `where(title: 'Volume').order(:value)` as a basis for this, or build up with a `left_outer_join` to restrict to one row.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is some sort of Entity Attribute Value system? What datatype is `value`? Is it a numerical type or a string?

Comment: Yes, it was EAV.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_attributes
end

class ProductAttribute < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end

Product.includes(:product_attributes)
    .where(product_attributes: {title: "Volume" })  
    .order('product_attributes.title ASC')
```

Reference for Order by the associations two levels deep.

[Rails order by association field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616611/rails-order-by-association-field)

Reference for Rails, querying associated records with conditions

[Rails, querying associated records with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968004/rails-querying-associated-records-with-conditions)

You can also use Scope With Argument like below

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_attributes

  scope :sort_by_product_attribute_title, ->(title){
    includes(:product_attributes)
        .where(product_attributes: {title: title }) 
        .order('product_attributes.title ASC')  }  
end

class ProductAttribute < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end

Product.sort_by_product_attribute_title("Volume")
```

Comment: One of the potential issues here is that even through you are doing an outer join the where clause still applies to the entire query and not just the joined rows.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different possible solutions - one them is to do a custom join with an additional restiction in the ON clause:

```ruby
class Product < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :product_attributes

  def self.order_by_volume
    joins(join_on_product_attribute('Volume'))
      .order("volumes.value desc")
  end

  private 

  def self.join_on_product_attribute(title, join_alias = title.downcase.pluralize)
    products, attrs = Product.arel_table, ProductAttribute.arel_table.alias(join_alias)
    products.join(attrs, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin)
               .on(
                 products[:id].eq(attrs[:product_id])
                   .and(attrs[:title].eq(title))
               )
               .join_sources.first
  end
end
```

```ruby
irb(main):084:0> Product.order_by_volume
  Product Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" LEFT OUTER JOIN "product_attributes" "volumes" ON "products"."id" = "volumes"."product_id" AND "volumes"."title" = 'Volume' ORDER BY volumes.value desc
```

Other possible solutions are a subquery or a lateral join to select the rows off the product_attributes table that just correspond to the volume attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems applicable. But I changed the design completely. Apologies for the delayed response.